# Move list of acronyms to the right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, acronyms

I'm using the `acronym` package and I want to move the list of acronyms a bit to the right.
I have the list in an independent `.tex` file and the code I use is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\begin{document}
\section{Description}
\acs{MLS}, \acl{TES}, \acf{HiRDLS}.
\section*{List of Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{MLS}{Microwave Limb Sounder}
\acro{HiRDLS}{High-Resolution Dynamics Limb Sounder}
\acro{TES}{Tropospheric Emission Sounder}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

I have played with `\hbox` and `\hspace` with no results.
Anyone knows about it?

Edit: Now with a compilable example.

Comment: Can you prepare a little compilable example showing the most important infos, i.e. your document class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it behaves like a list, you can modify the value of `\itemindent`.

Add the following lines to your preamble and adjust `0cm` to fit your needs

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\AC@@acro}{\setlength{\itemindent}{0cm}}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\AC@@acro}{\setlength{\itemindent}{0cm}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Description}
\acs{MLS}, \acl{TES}, \acf{HiRDLS}.
\section*{List of Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{MLS}{Microwave Limb Sounder}
\acro{HiRDLS}{High-Resolution Dynamics Limb Sounder}
\acro{TES}{Tropospheric Emission Sounder}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was something easier playing with \hspace or similar.